# i cant change my primary installation to opt/mqm/

Tags: ibm-mq

```
root@SPTS-Linux01:/opt/mqm/bin# ./setmqinst -i -p /opt/mqm/
AMQ6294E: Failed to create symbolic link with the name
'/usr/lib/libmqmzf.so'. Error Number: 2
1 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
2 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
3 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
4 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
5 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
6 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
7 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.``
8 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
9 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
10 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
11 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
12 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
13 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
14 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
15 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
16 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
17 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
18 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
19 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
20 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
21 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
22 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
23 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
24 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
25 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
26 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
27 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
28 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
29 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
30 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
31 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
32 of 32 tasks have been rolled back.
AMQ8577E: Failed to set 'Installation1' (/opt/mqm) as the primary installation.
AMQ8580E: Failed to unset 'Installation1' (/opt/mqm) as the primary
installation.
root@SPTS-Linux01:/opt/mqm/bin#
```

*this is the errors*

1. i have been trying for days i i always get stuck hereas a result i cant create QMGRS.
2. please if possible contact me i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please paste the text of the actual error into your question.

Comment: Can you also add the output from the dspmqinst command into your question please?

Comment: Please don't keep adding screen shots.   The output is text,  just cut and paste it into your question.   If you don't one how to format it,  just and tripple backticks on the line above and below your text of the output.

Comment: Please add the output of `dspmqinst` as requested by @MoragHughson.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary installation is MQ v7.0.1 then you cannot change it to something else.  As it says [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=installations-changing-primary-installation), if you have MQ v7.0.1 installed then it ***must*** be the primary installation.  The only way to change it is to un-install MQ v7.0.1.  The setmqinst command can only be used against MQ v7.1 or higher installations.

Comment: i am trying to add MQ V9

Answer (score 0):

```
root@SPTS-Linux01:/opt/mqm/bin# cd /usr/
root@SPTS-Linux01:/usr# ls
bin  config  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src
root@SPTS-Linux01:/usr# mkdir
root@SPTS-Linux01:/usr# mkdir lib64
root@SPTS-Linux01:/usr# ls
bin  config  games  include  lib  lib64  local  sbin  share  src
root@SPTS-Linux01:/usr# cd /opt/mqm/bin/
root@SPTS-Linux01:/opt/mqm/bin# ./setmqinst -i -p /opt/mqm
143 of 143 tasks have been completed successfully.
'Installation1' (/opt/mqm) set as the primary installation.
```

Comment: Does this imply that your issue is now fixed?

Comment: What was done to fix it?  Did you have to create `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`?

Comment: yes i had to create lib64 ,which wasnt there and evrything went on fine after that